# Web browsers don't support 1920x1080 (VGA)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display, display-resolution, browser

Video example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rgpnrDvZXk4

Ubuntu 20.04.4, 1080p 60hz VGA monitor that's using a VGA to DVI adapter to connect to my GTX 1070. The CPU is Ryzen 5 1600.

There are absolutely zero problems while trying to do anything else besides using web browsers (Chromium and Firefox) on 1920x1080 resolution. Whenever I do that, my monitor keeps losing and gaining signal in intervals that are a couple of seconds long. It displays "VGA no signal", goes blank, then comes back on again.

As soon as I close/minimize the browsers, the problems disappear, and then reappear once I open them again.

It is worth noting that this problem does not occur while using a direct VGA signal from an older GPU (R7 250). I know for a fact that there is nothing wrong with my 1070 and the adapter, as I use both of those on Windows where I was unable to recreate this issue.

**What didn't help:**

-Switching between available drivers.

-Updating my GPU firmware.

-Trying a different Ubuntu version.

**Notes:**

*Disabling hardware acceleration in Firefox did improve the experience, but it didn't fix the problem entirely.

*This issue occurs across other distros as well (Mint, Debian and Manjaro). On Debian this exact problem is present even during the OS installation making it nearly impossible to complete.

Comment: *"Web browsers don't support 1920x1080"*  don't think your theory is correct. 1920x1080 is the most common screen resolution for desktop web browsers... by a huge margin.

Comment: @Nmath I meant that as in they don't support 1920x1080 on my hardware. I couldn't recreate the problem on other systems so I'm trying to figure out what is it that Linux doesn't like about my setup.

Comment: It looks like the adapter has limits, and doesn't cope well with task at hand. I am also not sure what is has to do with browsers.

Comment: @mikewhatever I am also suspicious of the interface incompatibility. DVI draws a lot of attention since my brother also has a VGA monitor, but he is connecting it via HDMI adapter and has none of these issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't run a test with a newer monitor because I don't have one available BUT I did try using a VGA to HDMI adapter and it works!

Don't know how that idea hasn't occurred to me earlier. I guess I was convinced that, since outside of browsers the issues were non existent, it must be a software/driver incompatibility. Nope, turns out Linux just hates VGA to DVI-D conversion for whatever reason.